# Preventing power LED runaway with voltage and PWM

Tags: led-driver, theory

Using near-minimum voltage for the LEDs to light up, and PWM to control brightness by not allowing the frequency/brightness to go above a certain point.

Comments are telling me its not okay to not to be in control of the current.Will it still end up running away?

What if I made a thermal to PWM circuit that adjusts the PWM as heat goes up? Will it just end up going so low frequency that it is eventually visible to the eye?

Comment: You need a current limited supply.

Comment: Please don’t use voltage sources to drive LEDs. LEDs are current driven.

Comment: PWM doesn't (shouldn't) change the frequency.  The pulses come at the same rate, they are just narrower.  (The time between pulses is fixed, only the width of the pulses changes.  That's why it's called "pulse **width** modulation.")

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no, not a good solution.

What you are describing is a temperature controlled LED driver which could work in theory. Though you'd have to measure the die temperature which is barely possible with a temperature sensor (the common way to measure die temperature in-application would be to monitor the LEDs' forward voltage, which is temperature dependent).

But still, this would most likely not give you the desired result as the brightness would not be constant (which certainly is the main goal when driving LEDs).

The proper way of driving LEDs is to provide them with constant current and therefore get defined brightness and a well-known power dissipation. You then choose an appropriate heat sink that can handle the amount of dissipated power to keep the die temperature in an acceptable range.

Two ways to get defined LED current:

1. Series resistance. This will not exactly give you constant, but at least *limited* current. The LEDs will survive, but you'll notice slight variantions in brightness. Also, the resistor will waste some power.
2. Closed-loop current control using a dedicated driver.

Answer (score 2):

For high power LEDs, you need a constant current power supply to set the maximum current.  This will set the maximum brightness of the LED and it will protect the LED against thermal runaway and over-voltage.

If you use a commercially available LED constant current power supply, then you will usually find that it has a PWM input to control the brightness.

If you implement your own, then you will have to implement a PWM input for dimming.  The PWM won't be for protection, though.  It'll be really just for dimming.

---

Typical constant current power supplies use what amounts to pulse width modulation together with an inductor.

They turn on the current to the LED and measure the current through it.  When the current reaches a set level, they turn off the current.  The inductor keeps that current flowing through the LED for a (very short) period (some milliseconds to tens of milliseconds.)

When the current drops too low, the controller turn the current on again and the cycle repeats.

It is a form of pulse width modulation, but monitoring the current rather than the temperature or voltage.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I wanted to discuss with commenters by commenting comments as nobody had made an answer, but seems not possible. Anyways, what if I made a thermal to PWM circuit that adjusts the PWM as heat goes up? Will it just end up going so narrow...the pulse...that no light gets output. I dont have any lm317 left and my local electronics store is not open. I guess i could take components out of the rc car i scrapped

Comment: It doesn't sound like you have much in the way of parts.  A constant current supply made of an LM317 would work.  It would be the simplest - by far simpler than trying to measure temperature and regulate the PWM.  The downside to the LM317 is that it would get warm (maybe hot) depending on how much current your LED needs.

Comment: "Anyways, what if I made a thermal to PWM circuit that adjusts the PWM as heat goes up? Will it just end up going so narrow...the pulse...that no light gets output."  I don't see any way that it could get so hot that the PWM shuts down, but at the same time it's so dim you can't see the LED.  LEDs get too hot if you put too much power through them.